# Convergence of sequence of Lebesgue integrals

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, weak-convergence

Suppose we have a sequence of non-negative random variables $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which are integrable with respect to a probability measure $P$.  Denote $\mu_n \equiv E(X_n)$ and suppose that $\mu_n$ converges to a limit in $\mathbb{R}$, say $\mu$.

Suppose $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$.  Is it true that $E(X) = \mu$?

It is true that $E(X)$ is well defined, as $|x|$ is a non-negative continuous function so that $E(|X|) \leq \liminf E(|X_n|) = \mu < \infty$ by the Portmanteau lemma.

I know that uniform integrability of the $X_n$ will guarantee the convergence, but I'm not sure if this is true or even needed for the problem.  Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That is not true in general.

Take $f_n = n\cdot 1_{[0, 1/n]}$, which converges almost everywhere to $f = 0$. In particular, they converge in distribution as random variables on $[0, 1]$.
However, we have

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n = 1 > 0 = \int f. $$

**Aside:**

After obtaining a Skorohod representation it boils down to Fatou's lemma. So it is hard to do better.

Comment: What happens if $E(X_n^k)$ exists for each $k, n$ and $E(X_n^k) \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu_k \in \mathbb{R}$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$?  Then does $E(X^k) = \mu_k$?  I'm trying to understand the proof of the "method of moments" concept

Comment: @qp212223 In that case the answer is YES. This follows from uniform integrability of $(X_n^{k})$ for each $k$.

Comment: And just to double check, this is due to $\sup_k E|X_n|^2k < \infty$ and the function $x^2$ is obviously super-linear?

Comment: @qp212223 At least for real-valued variables you are safe: $\sup_n E|X_n^k|^2 = \sup_n E X_n^{2k} < \infty$ as the sequence converges.